# Responsive text to small on revolution slider

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, media-queries, revolution-slider

I am using the revolution slider on Wordpress in order to showcase client testimonials which are pulling from posts. When it gets to smaller screens the responsive text becomes too small and I don't want to just hide it when it gets to smaller screens. Other people are having similar issues and are having to add custom css. I added a media query which works for other elements (adding blue background for testing) but not for the text size. It's like its being ignored. This was the code that I added.

```
@media (max-width: 400px){
  #responsive-text {
    background-color:blue;
    font-size:21px !important;
  }
}
```

I am not sure if I am just targeting the wrong thing since it is pulling from posts but I have tried targeting multiple things without success. Here is the link to the page where the slider is located. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

http://jordandesignbuildgroup.com/jdbg2015/about/